# How to apply filter to pairwise?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have the stream:

```
 this.unselectedObjectsIds$ = this.selectedObjectsIds$.pipe(pairwise());
```

Where `this.selectedObjectsIds$` is

```
[
   ['131086', '131089', '131090', '131638', '132139'], 
   ['131086', '131089']
]
```

I try to apply this fiilter to the stream:

```js
this.unselectedObjectsIds$ = this.selectedObjectsIds$.pipe(
    pairwise(), 
    map((a) => a[0].filter(x => !a[1].includes(x))
);
```

Filter is:

```
a[0].filter(x => !a[1].includes(x));
```

But it does not work for me.

Comment: why do you need pairwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pairwise` is waiting for the next value

Because you have only one value - it is array: `[['131086', '131089', '131090', '131638', '132139'], ['131086', '131089']]`

if `selectedObjectsIds$` is `BehaviorSubject` for example

you need send a new value
`selectedObjectsIds$.next([])` and your code will be paired as

```
[[['131086', '131089', '131090', '131638', '132139'], ['131086', '131089']], []]
```

I will try to guess what you are going to have in OUTPUT:

is it `["131090", "131638", "132139"]`?

if yes - then use next snippet

```
import { map, pairwise, take, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { BehaviorSubject, interval, of } from 'rxjs';

const selectedObjectsIds$ = new BehaviorSubject([
  ['131086', '131089', '131090', '131638', '132139'],
  ['131086', '131089'],
]);

const unselectedObjectsIds$ = selectedObjectsIds$.pipe(
  tap((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  }),
  map(([arr1, arr2]) => {
    console.log(arr1);
    console.log(arr2);
    return arr1.filter((x) => !arr2.find((i) => i === x));
  })
);
unselectedObjectsIds$.subscribe((data) => console.log(data));
```

demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-i4nazm?file=index.ts